# Need to change name used sec:authentication in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

The credentials used to login is username and password. I want to display name in the home page

```
      <span sec:authentication="name">bob</span>
```

But it is only giving username used during login process. How to do it. I am using spring mvc. Please help

Comment: name must be defined in your authentication object, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the user from Spring Security Context and cast it to your "User" model then treat it as you like. In this example i'm using a @ModelAttribute that you could add in your controller or your advisor (@ControllerAdvice)

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public MyCustomUser getUser() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated() && !"anonymousUser".equals(auth.getPrincipal())) {
        return (MyCustomUser) auth.getPrincipal();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Then in your html `<span th:text="${user} ? ${user.name} : Bob">Bob</span>`